# MAC OS: Nmap module on Python3 imports in interpreter, but not script

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, nmap

Here's where I'm at.

I installed the latest stable build of nmap (7.91) with Homebrew, and installed the python modules using `pip3 install python3-nmap`

When I attempt to run a python3 script that has `import nmap` at the top I am met with this error:

`ImportError: No module named nmap`

But if I launch the interpreter with `python3` and then run

```
>>> import nmap
>>> dir(nmap)
```

Everything works fine and I'm met with this output:

```
['ET', 'PortScanner', 'PortScannerAsync', 'PortScannerError', 'PortScannerHostDict', 'PortScannerYield', 'Process', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__last_modification__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', 'convert_nmap_output_to_encoding', 'csv', 'io', 'nmap', 'os', 're', 'shlex', 'subprocess', 'sys']
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you're using two different virtual environments, and `nmap` was installed on the latter one that you're running iPython in.

Comment: That was it. Script runs now. Thanks.